# Rust and C compatibility with Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, rust

Is it possible to create a static library compiled with rustc and link it to an executable compiled with MSVC?

Comment: I imagine it's theoretically possible; you'd have to match the decorated function names, calling conventions, parameters, and return types. Why not create a dll and build a thunk layer in C? Probably will end up being more stable.

Comment: I would rather stay away from DLLs for performance reasons...

Comment: In my experience, they are fine one you've called a function once and can cache the function pointer.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I lack the expertise with MVSC and in general the Windows way of things; on Linux the answer is a resounding yes because there Rust can match the C ABI (using `extern` function declarations). I naively thought that C on Windows was simple as well (contrary to C++), that is had a single calling convention, etc... otherwise as its a role of Rust to provide a C ABI, it will require some tweaking.

Comment: @Bathsheba Do you have documentation on how this caching mechanism works? I always assumed that the cost of a DLL function call was roughly similar to the cost of a virtual function call.

Comment: I use something on these lines: typedef jint (JNICALL *PFN_GET)(JavaVM **vmBuf, jsize bufLen, jsize *nVMs);
                static PFN_GET pfn = NULL;
                if (pfn == NULL){
                    pfn = (PFN_GET)GetProcAddress(s_jni_library, "JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs");
                }

Comment: @Bathsheba Ah I see. That seems faster than a virtual function call, but still not as fast as a static function call. You can't inline and you have the overhead of the pointer check and the overhead of a function pointer call.

Comment: If performance is *that* critical then you'll have to force the static linkage. I've never tried it but as I've already said, I imagine it is possible, with some pain. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use only `rustc` to produce a static library, you will do this by specifying some attributes in your crate's `lib.rs` file, and marking exported functions as so:

```
#![crate_type = "static_lib"]
#![crate_name = "mylib"]

use libc::c_int;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn my_exported_func(num: c_int) -> c_int {
    num + 1
}
```

Then simply invoke `rustc lib.rs`. This applies to all platforms that `rustc` supports.

In a C/C++ header, add:

```
#pragma once

// only use extern block if the header is put inside a C++ CU
extern "C" {
    int my_exported_func(int num);
}
```

and link the output `.lib` or `.a` as necessary.

For Cargo, you can specify the crate type and name in your `Cargo.toml`.

Sources:

- http://rustbyexample.com/attribute/crate.html
- https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ffi.html

Comment: Be careful, Rust's `i32` is not necessarily equivalent to C's `int`.

Comment: Use `libc::c_int` instead.